# Why do I get undefined when I use elements from a node-list or HTML-Collection when traversing the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal

While traversing the DOM there are sometimes many child elements under one parent.

I can get these children as either node-lists using a `querySelectorAll` or I can get them as HTML-Collections by using `element.children`.

But when I select one to use to put in my DOM tree traversal I get `undefined`.

I have tried turning the node-lists and HTML-Collections into arrays and using them that way with no success.  I have tried using for-of loops regular for loops and foreach loops for selecting a single element, yet always with failure `undefined`.

I have created a made up situation that shows this situation, although the problem is solvable without having to Traverse the DOM, you have to image that it is necessary.

- HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Testing</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="eric_meyer_reset_2.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="topOfPage">
            <header>
               <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="simulated RNG">
               <p>Your number is: <span id="theRandomNumber">2</span></p>
               <button type="button" id="prizeOpenButton">Press for Prize</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="bottomOfPage">
            <!-- These sections are added dynamically during the script operation -->
            <section class="joy" data-id="0">Hurray</section>
            <section class="joy" data-id="1">Hurrah</section>
            <section class="joy" data-id="2">Yay</section>
            <section class="joy" data-id="3">Congrats</section>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

- CSS

```
.joy {
   display: none
}
```

- JavaScript

```
const randomNumber = document.getElementById("theRandomNumber");
const prizeButton = document.getElementById("prizeOpenButton")

let matchNumberToPrizeSection = function (event) {
   let prizeSections = document.querySelectorAll(".joy");

   let theSection = null;

   for (let i = 0; i < prizeSections.length; i++) {
      if (prizeSections[i].dataset.id === randomNumber) {
         theSection = prizeSections[i];
      }
   }

   // lets say for some reason we have to traverse the DOM
   // starting with the button going to the "theSection" above
   let winningSection = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.theSection;

   console.log(winningSection.innerHTML);
}
prizeButton.addEventListener("click", matchNumberToPrizeSection);
```

Comment: It looks like `winningSection` is never defined, is this the full code?

Comment: I will go back and define it, but it still won't change the outcome.

Comment: That's ok, I just want to eliminate the possibility of typos before I attempt to answer.

Comment: Probably because you are trying to target elements before they have been dynamically added to the DOM. Try console logging out prizeSections after it is declared, I imagine it will be null, basically an empty NodeList

Comment: thanks for finding another issue with my code.  however I am not targeting elements before they have been added to the DOM.  Declaring prizeSections will have no effect on the issue.  I will however fix my error and ensure that fact.

Comment: `let winningSection = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.theSection;` doesn't really make sense, no DOM element has a `.theSection` property. Didn't you just want to output `theSection.innerHTML`? Not sure what this parent-element-next-element traversal is meant to achieve

Comment: it was already declared.  The Node list is not empty and neither is it in my actual code.

Comment: Btw, you'll want to use `.dataset.id === randomNumber.textContent` not `=== randomNumber` (comparing to the element itself)

Comment: "*when I select one to use to put in my DOM tree traversal I get `undefined`.*" - what exactly is your problem? Are you complaining that `theSection` always ends up as `undefined` after your loop over `prizeSections`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot use node-list or HTML-Collection elements directly or indirectly when you are building up a DOM traversal.  What I finally found was that I can use the element before the many child elements, in my original question that was a `div` with id of bottomOfPage.  What I had to do was find the index of the child element that I needed using the node-list elements and use that index in the parent `div` like this.  `event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children(index)`

Answer (score 0):

I saw a number of issues, but the below code works.

For one, you were comparing elements instead of the text of the element, or the data-id.  I went through and cleaned up the inconsistencies there.

1. this is returning an element

```
const randomNumber = document.getElementById("theRandomNumber");
```

- but your are comparing it with a  number `dataset.id`. They will never match

```
if (prizeSections[i].dataset.id === randomNumber)
```

2. 

```
let winningSection = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.theSection
```

- the variable `theSection` is pointing to an element, and that is not a property of `nextElementSibling`.  I you want to do the element chaining and search for an element that is a child of `nextElementSibling`, then call `querySelector` on it and pass in an id or class, or whatever

```
let winningSection = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector([`data-id="${theSection.dataset.id}"`])
```

The above is redundant in this example, and I saw no reason to traverse the DOM like you did.  That's an easy way to create bugs, especially if you move around or add items to your markup.

Since you have the `data-id`, you can query the entire document for that id.  This will be hardened to changes to the DOM in the future.

```js
const randomNumber = document.getElementById("theRandomNumber").innerText;
const prizeButton = document.getElementById("prizeOpenButton")

let matchNumberToPrizeSection = function (event) {
   let prizeSections = document.querySelectorAll(".joy");

   let theSection = null;

   for (let i = 0; i < prizeSections.length; i++) {
      if (prizeSections[i].dataset.id === randomNumber) {
         theSection = prizeSections[i].dataset.id;
      }
   }

   let winningSection = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${theSection}"]`);

   console.log(winningSection.innerHTML);
}
prizeButton.addEventListener("click", matchNumberToPrizeSection);
```

```css
.joy {
   display: none
}
```

```html
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="topOfPage">
            <header>
               <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="simulated RNG">
               <p>Your number is: <span id="theRandomNumber">2</span></p>
               <button type="button" id="prizeOpenButton">Press for Prize</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="bottomOfPage">
            <!-- These sections are added dynamically during the script operation -->
            <section class="joy" data-id="0">Hurray</section>
            <section class="joy" data-id="1">Hurrah</section>
            <section class="joy" data-id="2">Yay</section>
            <section class="joy" data-id="3">Congrats</section>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The whole reason for this was to imagine having to traverse the DOM and solve my problem.  This was just a made up problem.  I can give you my real code, but it is quite long.  The problem is every time I try to traverse the DOM and I have to use an element from a node-list or a HTML-collection, I get undefined.

Comment: Ok, that's fine and all, and however you traverse the DOM seems to be separate from the reason you're getting undefined.  There were the inconsistencies I mentioned.  I will update my answer to point to them specifically.

Comment: It's not clear why you changed `theSection = prizeSections[i];` into `theSection = prizeSections[i].dataset.id;`, that just assigns the `randomNumber` to `theSection`. Sure, one could have replaced the entire loop with just `const theSection = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${randomNumber}"]`);`, but I don't think that's the OP's point.

Comment: @Bergi there is a lot that could be refactored in this code example, but to my point, the issues OP was running into were not node-list, or HTML-collection based.  I made updates to improve clarity.

Comment: Thanks again PsiKai.  If you try it yourself in a better example, that would be fine.  I stand by the fact that while trying to traverse the DOM you are unable to use elements from either node-lists or HTML-collections.  THis is my problem and I apologize for what has turned out to be a bad example problem.